# Does this function conform to ANSI SQL standard?

Tags: mysql, sql, function, standards, ansi-sql

I was wondering if anyone can tell me if this function follows ANSI SQL standard, and for future reference are there any resources that i can use to find if my SQL conforms to ANSI standards. And the DBMS i am using is MySQL.

```
CREATE FUNCTION INCREMENT()
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE oldVal INT;
    DECLARE newVal INT;
    SELECT currentVal INTO oldVal FROM atable FOR UPDATE;
    SET newVal=oldVal +1;
    UPDATE atable SET currentVal=newVal;
    RETURN newVal;
END;
```

Comment: In general, I would just suggest getting a copy of MS SQL Express and running your function there as well.  If it runs in MySql and it runs in MS SQL then you should be good.

Comment: That does not help Linux folks, and more importantly still does not guarantee compliance to standards.

Comment: @mvp, if he really needs to be 100% positively compliant then yes he can go get the official document and learn it through and through.  Or he can do something like what I suggested and in the rare case that something he wrote runs in both those platforms but still isn't SQL compliant AND doesn't run in some other target platform (which is the goal, right?) then he can fix those issues as they come up.

Comment: What's wrong with `UPDATE table SET current = current + 1`?

Comment: Try this on SQL Fiddle.  You'll discover that it doesn't parse on most databases.  The standard, alas, has some holes and flexibility . . . so code can technically meet the standard but still not run on most databases (so long as the exceptions are documented).

Comment: @eggyal basically i need to retrieve the new updated value if i do `UPDATE table SET current = current + 1` and then perform a select to get the new value, this could cause issues as what if another transaction updates between the update and select.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: MySQL and SQL Server do not define the SQL standard. And if a function runs there, then it most definitely doesn't fullfill the ANSI standard.

Comment: @jcs: no DBMS completely complies with the SQL standard - and especially not when it comes to stored procedures and functions (and MySQL does deviate from the standard quite often. DB2 and PostgreSQL are much closer to the standard than MySQL).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I meant (though clearly I didn't state it) to run it on whatever 2 or 3 databases you're most likely to target... so through fiddle in there if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a validation tool that can check if your SQL conforms to SQL 2003.
http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment

> basically i need to retrieve the new updated value if i do UPDATE
>   table SET current = current + 1 and then perform a select to get the
>   new value, this could cause issues as what if another transaction
>   updates between the update and select.

I don't think your problem has anything at all to do with SQL standards. I think your problem has to do with [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html) and with [transaction isolation levels.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level)